# Bokeh Range Set Only 1 Bound

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I would expect the following code to set only the upper bound of the plot y range, however the lower bound is also inexplicably set to 0:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bkp
import numpy as np

bkp.output_file("/tmp/test_plot.html")
fig = bkp.figure(y_range=[None, 100]) # plot y range: 0-100
# fig = bkp.figure() # plot y range: 50-100
fig.line(np.linspace(0, 1, 200), np.random.random(200)*50+50) # number range: 50-100
bkp.save(fig)
```

Why does this happen? What's the easiest way to set only 1 range bound?

Comment: same problem using `Range1d(start=None, end=100)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are replacing the auto-ranging default `DataRange1d` with a "dumb" (non-auto ranging) `Range1d`. Set the `end` value of the default range that the plot creates, without replacing the entire range. Or alternatively, replace with a new `DataRange1d`:

```
from bokeh.models import DataRange1d
p = figure(y_range=DataRange1d(end=100))
```

or

```
p.y_range.end = 100
```

Comment: Thanks! `import bokeh.models as bkm` and `fig = bkp.figure(y_range=bkm.DataRange1d(end=100))` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The `Range1d(start=None, end=100)` (as you are also referring to in your comments) is only defining your initial view. It doesn't make sense for a Range to not have both a starting point and an ending point, so if you give it `start=None`, it will just use its default value which is `0`.

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

`Range1D(start=value1, end=value2, bounds=(None, 100))`

This will give you an upper bound of 100 and no lower bound.

See [docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.Range1d) for more specifications and examples.

Edit: okay, I initially ready your question as though you were trying to set the bounds. You want to use the `DataRange1D` class instead, then. If you just make sure to not override the `start`, it will default to "auto".
In other words, this should do what you want:

`DataRange1D(end=100)`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Looking at the docs, it seems like bound controls how far the user can zoom out. I am interested in setting only 1 side of the initial view - similar to `plt.ylim(max=100)`.